# fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.mapView, mMapFragment) not works

Tags: android, fragmenttransaction

How can I to add the mapFragment in mapView?
Why can not this works?
What do I do that it works :)?

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {
  // ..............................................

FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
MapFragment mMapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.mapView, mMapFragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

**XML**

```
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_maps"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

cannot resolve method add

Comment: can you post your XML?

Comment: @AndyJoyce what for .... he is using wrong class ... FragmentActivity is for support fragments ... MapFragment extends android.app.Fragment ... a compile time error is obvious

Comment: now is more interesting(stupid) .... why are you wana replace fragment which is already inflated? use v4 FragmentManager.findFragmentById(...) to obtain the fragment via its id instead creating(wrong) new one

Comment: please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28991363/supportmapfragment-with-navigationdrawer) for `com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment`

Comment: i did it from example

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_google_maps.htm try this example. Hope this is what you need

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
MapFragment mMapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();
```

with

```
MapFragment mMapFragment = new MapFragment();
```